# What should I look at for a comparison between Google and Microsoft?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog

I'm going to be putting together a blog post(s) comparing the Cloud computing powers of both Google and Microsoft.  Here is a List of what I came up with to compare:

- **Email:**

  - labels
  - folders
  - junk
  - sync with outlook
  - all in one solution
  - alerts
- **Chat:**

  - Link to other chat clients
- **Calendar:**

  - sync with iPhone
  - sync with Android
  - sync with Outlook
- **Document Editors**

  - reliability
  - usability
- **Cloud Storage**

  - Space
- **Searching**

  - Google Googles vs Bing Images
  - Top results to desired page
  - Spam on front page

Are there any other features that I'm missing?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a series, stretch out the content since it'll be quite the turtle

Comment: Lifehacker has recently done something like this, have a look at their article and see if you want to "borrow" any bits from them. http://uk.lifehacker.com/5786884/cloud-storage-faceoff-windows-live-skydrive-vs-dropbox-vs-amazon-cloud-drive

Comment: I wonder if there's any benchmarks we could do performance wise

Comment: Only thing I can think of is downloading email into outlook @IvoFlipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed. Check the blog's [Battle of the Giants](http://blog.superuser.com/category/battle-of-the-giants/) category/